# How to create a regex with 13 characters and exact start?

Tags: regex

Hello I have a problem create regular expression (phone number) for the following conditions:

- must contain exactly 13 characters
- must only start +421 or +420
- only numbers must follow
- must ignore spaces

the finally format must be:
`+421 xxx xxx xxx` or `+420 xxx xxx xxx`

I've created something like this so far, but I have no idea how to proceed.

`const regexPhone = /^\+[0-9]{12}/i;`

Can you help me please?

Comment: Maybe this regex help you: `/^\+42[01](\s\d{3}){3}$/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex patterns are often created on the basis of how the text 'looks', like in your example the numbers should look like "+420 xxx xxx xxx", so why not make regex for this exact format?

Try this: `/^\+42[10] \d{3} \d{3} \d{3}$/`

```js
let pattern = /^\+42[10] \d{3} \d{3} \d{3}$/
let s = "+421 543 100 478"
console.log(pattern.test(s))
```

Now you can simplify the above regex to `/^\+42[10]( \d{3}){3}$/`

```
^             matches the start of the string
\+            matches +
42[10]        matches 42 followed by either 1 or 0
( \d{3}){3}   matches a space followed by three digits, this inturn is matched exactly three times
$             matches the end of the string
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and if we don't ignore spaces? Only ```/^\+42[10]$/``` ?

Comment: @TheDareback if you dont want space inbetween, then remove the space before \d{3}. It will become: `/^\+42[10](\d{3}){3}$/`.   `/^\+42[10]$/` will match only +420 or +421, it wont be able to match the rest of the phone number.